# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRTU_Module Linux / Shared library C code

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ld, .so

I have a problem compiling the following line of code :

```
gcc -o main.c -ldl -lpthread -lRTU_Module main.o
```

I have the following error message :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRTU_Module
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When i try to find the location of my .so it returns this :

```
locate libRTU_Module.so
/home/owasys/workspace/AccelTest/libRTU_Module.so
/home/owasys/workspace/Compiler_gcc-linaro-5.3_patch/files/lib/libRTU_Module.so
/home/owasys/workspace/Compiler_gcc-linaro-5.3_patch/files/lib/libRTU_Module.so.1.0.11
/opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/libRTU_Module.so
/opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/libRTU_Module.so.0
/opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/libRTU_Module.so.0.0.0
/opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/libRTU_Module.so.1.0.11
```

I have red multiple of answer to a similar question but i have not solve my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Using `-l` means you don't need to supply the `lib` prefix or the `.so` suffix

Answer (score 0):

`ld` normally scans a default/configured set of dirs, generally wouldn't know about custom stuff like /home/a/b/c

Should be easy enough to fix; does this work?

```
dir=/home/owasys/workspace/Compiler_gcc-linaro-5.3_patch/files/lib
gcc -o main.c -ldl -lpthread -lRTU_Module.so main.o -L $dir
```

May need to tell the runtime link editor to search there as well, eg adding this to gcc cmd-line:

```
-Wl,-rpath=$dir
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I have a question, where the .so should be located to be find by the ld command ?

Comment: Most any directory should be OK, one that's accessible to you and possibly others; specify that dir with both `-L /path/to/dir` and `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/dir` .   What isn't working? (unspecified above).  Try running your program with `strace`, that often helps to isolate issues with files, locations, permissions, others.   (note: leading - with -rpath, answer updated).